In Xcode I am getting ( No Accounts: Add a new account in Accounts settings. ) while create build
In Xcode I am getting ( No Accounts: Add a new account in Accounts settings. ) while create build.
Helpfull solution for this error
And also for how to connect iPhone with Xcode I don't know please anyone help me to resolve that


Open Xcode:
Launch Xcode on your Mac.

2.Open Preferences:
Go to the Xcode menu in the top left corner of the screen.
Select Preferences... or press Command + ,

Select Accounts:
In the Preferences window, click on the Accounts tab.

Add an Account:
Click on the + button at the bottom left of the Accounts pane.
Choose Apple ID and click Continue.

Sign In:
Enter your Apple ID and password. If you have two-factor authentication enabled, you'll also need to enter the verification code sent to your device.

Confirm:
After signing in, your Apple ID should appear in the list of accounts, and Xcode should now be able to access your developer credentials.

Select a Team:
Go to your project settings by clicking on the project in the Navigator, then selecting the General tab.
Under the Signing & Capabilities section, make sure that your team is selected. If you haven't set up a team yet, you might need to create one in the Apple Developer portal.

Create Build:
Now you should be able to create a build. Go to Product > Archive to start the build process.



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
